# Why is my large NEMA 34 stepper motor so weak?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

I bought this motor from [StepperOnline](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/p-series-ip65-waterproof-nema-34-stepper-motor-6-0a-4-5nm-637-38oz-in-34ip65-45). It's a NEMA 34 stepper motor 6.0 A 4.5 Nm.

I wired it like this (not to scale):
[image: wiring]

But I am using a variable power supply.

I have the power supply set to 30 V and 6 A, but the motor can only lift about 5 pounds. I noticed that it never uses more than 1.2 A. I tried playing around with different speeds and switch settings.

Here is current switch configuration:

[image]

[image]

**Why can this large stepper motor only lift 5 pounds? I was expecting it to lift way more. Also, why is it only using a max of 1.2 A instead of the rated 6 A?**

**Edit:**

Here is my setup. I had some rope at the end of the 3D printed part, which was holding some weight. The rope was 9cm away from the motor shaft.
[image]

**Edit 2:**

Here is the board:
[image]

Here is the Arduino code:

```
#define driverPUL1 2  // PUL pin 1
#define driverDIR1 3  // Dir pin 1
#define enablePIN1 4  // enable pin 1

#define potPin A0

void setup() {
  pinMode(driverPUL1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(driverDIR1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enablePIN1, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("setup");
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite (driverDIR1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (enablePIN1, HIGH);

  int value = map(analogRead(potPin), 0, 1023, 255, 0);
  Serial.println(value);

  if (value !=  255) {
    digitalWrite(driverPUL1, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(value);
    digitalWrite(driverPUL1, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(value);
  }
}
```

Here's a picture of the power supply while I'm holding the motor still with my hand (applying only about 5 pounds), you can see that it's only using 1 A.

[image]

My power supply is set to 6.4 A:

[image]

Comment: when you say "lift 5lbs", at what moment arm is that? A picture of your mechanical setup is important. 5lbs is 22 newtons, which yields 4.5Nm at a 20cm moment arm.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my OP

Comment: According to the datasheet you're using a microstepping of 32 - that can cause torque loss as well: https://www.machinedesign.com/archive/article/21812154/microstepping-myths , perhaps try 400/steps/rev for a microstepping of 2?

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still having the same problem. I tried several different switch configurations

Comment: I've seen some knockoff versions of these drivers before. Any chance you can open the housing (should just be two Phillips screws) and show us the board inside?

Comment: I edited my OP again

Comment: How rapidly are you sending pulses? Does your code implement acceleration or do you jump to full speed from a standstill? When you're sending no pulses, can you turn the motor by hand?

Comment: [This](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/DM860T.pdf) manual states a minimum supply voltage of 36VDC. Also you might need to set the power supply's current limit at >6A to get 6A output, depending.

Comment: I have a potentiometer connected to an Arduino Uno. I tried all different speeds. There's no acceleration built into the code, but I always put the potentiometer to 0 before I start it. I can easily move the 3d printed handle shown in my OP with my hand, even with it powered on

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany On my Stepper driver, it says "VAC: 18v ~80V or VDC: 24V ~110V. I must have a different version from what you linked

Comment: I note (bemusedly) that @Spehro's link is from the website printed on your box. Are there multiple DM860T's?

Comment: actually, there are (?!) https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/DM860T_V3.0.pdf

Comment: @Matt S, I think there are a few different versions. Here is the one I got: https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/digital-stepper-driver-2-4-7-2a-18-80vac-or-36-110vdc-for-nema-34-motor-dm860t

Comment: Is it possible that either the motor or driver is faulty? Should I contact Stepper Online?

Comment: You might be able to apply DC directly to one or two of the windings, to see if it supports the required load and supplies rated holding torque.

Comment: Is that safe? It won't cause any damage to my motor?

Comment: The "lever" looks about 95 mm from axle to notch. Ignoring the torque from the lever (can you get/print a balanced one?), 4.5 Nm would be about 42.8 N perpendicular to the lever, with the lever horizontal about 4.2 kg or 9.2 lbs "in the notch" - you're definitely in the right ball park already.

Comment: I think it would be safe to energize one winding with DC if current is within motor rating. This would be equivalent to having the motor hold a position. See what the specified holding or breakaway torque is.

Comment: @PStechPaul I energized one of the windings, and it consumed the full 6A, but I could still move the 3D printed handle easily with my hand by applying about 5 pounds of force.

Comment: Energizing one winding might produce half the rated torque. 5 lb at 9 cm (3.5") is 17.5 in-lb, which is about half the rated 39.8 in-lb. If the windings are isolated, you could try applying DC to both, probably in series and also 6A. One winding might need to be reversed. The motor and controller are probably within spec.

Comment: With 1/1.2 Amperes being *supply* current@~30 V, a "chopper" motor driver could drive bout 30 Watts into the motor phases. At 0.34 Ohms, 6 A is just about 12 Watts: That would allow a full 6A through two phases simultaneously.

Comment: The comments from greybeard and PStechPaul constitute a reasonable answer. One or other could make it so :-) .  ||

Comment: To be honest, I'm not understanding. Why is the motor only using 1A when it's rated for 6A?

Comment: The current reading at the PS gives the *supply* current of the motor driver. The motor driver can be understood a couple of controllable buck/step down converters: the *phase* (motor) current is several times the supply current, as the supply voltage needs to be several times the static winding voltage to achieve decent speed&acceleration.

Comment: Aright, so nothing is wrong with my motor then. It's simply much weaker than I thought it would be

Comment: The wire jumpers used to connect the motor controller to bench power supply clip leads look very thin, I wonder what the voltage is on the driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set 2 or 4 microsteps (it's 400 or 800 on driver); setting 6400 is the reason why you have little torque (only 4,9% of maximum torque). Higher voltage is essential too, but your voltage should be OK for holding still objects or slow motion.

[image: Table showing Incremental Torque per Microstep]

(Image source: [Faulhaber - Stepper Motor Tutorial - Microstepping Myths and Realities](https://www.faulhaber.com/en/know-how/tutorials/stepper-motor-tutorial-microstepping-myths-and-realities/))